# Open new Component in Fullscreen in QtQml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, fullscreen

I have a Qt application working with qml and c++. The Gui is several component deep. I would like to open a new Component ( a virtual Keyboard) in fullscreen mode, but opening this new module, shouldn't destroy the opened ones, just appear above them in full screen size.

I have tried opening this keyboard using c++ extension using the same QQuickView object. It works, but i am struggling to pass the keyboard focus to the new element.

This is how i opened the Virtual keyboard from a c++ callback function:

```
QQmlComponent component(viewer->engine(), QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/VirtualKeyboard.qml"));
keyboard = component.create();
QQmlProperty::write(keyboard, "parent", QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(static_cast<QObject*>(viewer->rootObject())));
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(keyboard, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
```

Is there any easier way to open the new component as a child element but in fullscreen?
Or what should i do to pass the focus to the new element. I have tried using the following codes, but none of them was working.

```
    viewer->rootObject()->childItems()[0]->setEnabled(false);   //original components
    viewer->rootObject()->childItems()[0]->setFocus(false);
    viewer->rootObject()->childItems()[1]->forceActiveFocus();  //virtual keyboard component
```

Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved it. I am not sure what was the error, but probably i have forgotten about making the VirtualKeyboard.qml to be a FocusScope element.

I have also modified the structure of GUI to drop popups and other message box windows more easily in fullscreen mode. I write down my final solution, it may be useful for others later.

First i have a main.qml which is run at start

```
Rectangle {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 600
    objectName: "mainWindow"

    Loader {
        objectName: "mainLoader"
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: ""

        onLoaded: item.objectName="loadedMain";
    }

    Loader {
        objectName: "popupLoader"
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: ""

        onLoaded: item.objectName="loadedPopup";
    }
}
```

In the c logic, used the following functions.

```
//How to open main windows
void MainUserSelection::showWindow(QString type) {

    QObject *main = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("mainLoader",Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    if (main==NULL)
        return;

    if (type=="SettingsWindow") {
        main->setProperty("source", "qml/Settings.qml");
        return;
    }
}

//how to open popups
void MainUserSelection::showPopup(QString type, QStringList params) {

    if (type=="PictureSelect") {

        QObject *main = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("popupLoader",Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
        if (main!=NULL) {
            main->setProperty("source", "qml/Popups/PictureSelect.qml");

            QQuickItem *item = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem *>("loadedPopup");
            if (item!=NULL)
                item->forceActiveFocus();

            if (params.count()>0)
                item->setProperty("textEnglish",params[0]);

            if (params.count()>1)
                item->setProperty("textHungarian",params[1]);
        }

        return;
    }

    if (type=="Keyboard") {

        QObject *main = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("popupLoader",Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
        if (main!=NULL) {
            main->setProperty("source", "qml/Popups/VirtualKeyboard.qml");

            QQuickItem *item = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem *>("loadedPopup");
            if (item!=NULL) {
                item->forceActiveFocus();
                if (params.count()>0)
                    item->setProperty("text",params[0]);

                if (params.count()>1)
                    item->setProperty("placeholder",params[1]);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}

//popup windows returns by calling this function
void MainUserSelection::popupReturned(QString type, QStringList params) {

    QObject *main = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("popupLoader",Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    if (main!=NULL)
        main->setProperty("source", "");

    QQuickItem *item = viewer->rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem *>("loadedMain");
    if (item!=NULL)
        item->forceActiveFocus();

    //also emit finish signal to main window qml
    emit popupFinished(type,params);
}
```

somewher in MainUserSelection class

```
viewer->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("userselection",this);
```

Finally i open popup from qml bye calling:

```
userselection.showPopup("PictureSelect","")
userselection.popupFinished.connect(someQmlReturnFunction);  //don't forget to disconnect
```